# Enable hibernate in Ubuntu 13.04 - editing hibernate.pkla doesn't work

Tags: hibernate

How do I enable the hibernate option. Editing `hibernate.pkla` doesn't work.

I did the following -

```
$ sudo gedit /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/hibernate.pkla
[Enable Hibernate]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes
```

and restarted, but nothing happens.

Comment: @JorgeCastro The answer there describes what's mentioned in the question. Any idea why that might not work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have not already found it, download and install dconf Editor from the Ubuntu Software Center

[image]

1. Start the programme
2. Click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to activate the search facility
3. Type in **Hibernate** and click the <kbd>Next</kbd> button
4. Make sure that the value for Hibernate is set to Hibernate, not inactive.

You're done.

[image]