# hibernate is diabled on ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: shutdown, hibernate, swap

I'm using ubuntu 13.04 and hibernate is disabled 
Do I need a big swap file to enable hibernate ?
How ?

Comment: already have answer...... [link][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/337471/enable-hibernate-in-ubuntu-13-04-editing-hibernate-pkla-doesnt-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernation has been disabled by default. Please follow instructions here: [How to enable hibernation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94754/how-to-enable-hibernation)

Comment: please it should be suggested in comment ,not as an answer..

Comment: It does answer the question, even if the question is probably a duplicate. And I think it is sensible to point out hat hibernation has been disabled by the developers as a precaution, it is not a "bug" of any sort.

Comment: you have referred this to somewhere, instead of doing this you could have made an answer or mentioned that address in the comment..